# Subscribing for Internet Printing Protocol (IPP) job events

Tags: java, printing

I am writing a IPP client in Java. I could successfully create a client which prints a single file and also queries the status of the job. As per the requirement I can say whether job is complete only when I get the final state of the job, example printing completed, job aborted, etc. Right now the job status is received by polling/querying the IPP server periodically. With this approach the performance depends heavily on the polling interval. Interval too high could mean delay in getting status, too low could mean unnecessary network bandwidth.

I came across this RFC 3995, which talks about subscribing to job events and getting notified when the event occurs on the printer/server.
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3995

But when I try to create job subscription, I always get response from printer that the operation is not supported. I also read that this is optional.

Questions:

1. Is this feature really available and implemented?
2. Is there any setting which I need to change which will enable this feature?
3. Any IPP version where it has been made mandatory?
4. Is there any other way I can efficiently query job status?

Comment: Hi Rahul, can you please show your existing code and the context under which your code is running (e.g. an applet, command line, etc.)?

Comment: Hi Vince. Its runs as command line utility. Please find below code snippet:
public int PrintJob(String ippHost) {
...
}

Comment: IppAttributeGroup subsGroup = new IppAttributeGroup(IppConstants.IppTag.IPP_TAG_SUBSCRIPTION);  subsGroup.addAttribute(IppConstants.IppTag.IPP_TAG_KEYWORD, "notify-pull-method", "ippget");
subsGroup.addAttribute(IppConstants.IppTag.IPP_TAG_INTEGER, "notify-job-id", jobId);
   
IppRequest request = new IppRequest();   request.setOperationId(IppConstants.IppOperation.IPP_CREATE_JOB_SUBSCRIPTION);
...
IppResponse ippResponse = this.SendRequest(ippHost, request);
...

Comment: Does your company own the source? I'd like to start new a open source project independent of CUPS, CUPS4J or jspi. Would you or your company be willing to support this?

Comment: Hello Peter,

I can't talk for my company, probably not.
But I can help out. What kind of support are you expecting ?

Rahul.

Comment: In the meantime I've started my open source ipp implementation: https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. Create-Job-Subscription: [IPP reference implementation CUPS](https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-ipp.html) >= 1.2
2. very unlikely, usually you can just enable or disable IPP
3. No. optional in [IPP 2.2 (Page 20)](http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/standards/std-ipp20-20151030-5100.12.pdf), not required in [IPP Everywhere (Page 34)](http://ftp.pwg.org/pub/pwg/candidates/cs-ippeve10-20130128-5100.14.pdf)
4. probably not. I doubt that manufacturers own protocols support this kind of "push"

[We](http://ipp-software.de) do polling as well (e.g. every 5 seconds). Some printers don't handle concurrent IPP requests very well, so be careful :-)

**[UPDATE]**

My Kotlin library https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin supports subscriptions and events.

Comment: Thanks Peter for your answers.

Regarding your last comment about concurrent IPP requests, I experienced it on the printer I was testing. Second concurrent job failied BUSY status. I need to handle it differently.

Rahul.

Comment: Peter, if I've understood correctly, [CUPS doesn't support **notify-wait=true**](https://github.com/apple/cups/issues/2601) so it will be polling anyway, isn't? I know that it is an old issue but is flagged with "Will Not Fix"